# winexe error: Cannot connect to svcctl pipe. NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED

Tags: winexe

Am trying to execute the following winexe command, but it throws 'ERROR: Cannot connect to svcctl pipe. NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED.'

```
winexe -U domain/username%password //windows_machine ipconfig
```

debug info shows,

```
ERROR: smb_raw_open_recv - NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED
ERROR: on_ctrl_pipe_error - NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED
ERROR: Cannot open control pipe - NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED
```

When i have 'winexesvc.exe' in Windows machine, the command works.

My understanding according to http://opensourceinfo.blogspot.com/ is that winexe itself creates winexesvc service, starts it and tries to connect to control pipe.  If that's the case, what setting should i have in Windows to resolve Access Denied error and get the service installed successfully? Please correct me if am wrong.

I also came across similar issue in https://sourceforge.net/p/winexe/bugs/35/ post, but am unable to understand the given resolution *'I was trying to log on via a domain user, but only local users were configured'*

Note that I have already set, 
1. Network Access: Sharing and security model for
local accounts" to "Classic – local users authenticate as themselves 
2. LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy to 1.

So do we need to manually place winexesvc.exe in Windows machine for winexe to work or can we fix the above Access Denied error?

Thanks in advance.